# Picking integers satisfying a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\delta_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers decreasing to $0$. Let $t>0$ be a fixed real number. Then can we find some integers $N_n$ such that $N_n \delta_n \rightarrow t$? We don't know anything about the $\delta_n$ other than the fact that they go to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Note that for each $n$ there exists some integer $N_n$ such that $N_n\delta_n\leq t<(N_n+1)\delta_n$ (explicitly, $N_n=\lfloor t/\delta_n\rfloor$).  In particular, we have $|N_n\delta_n-t|<\delta_n$ and so $N_n\delta_n\to t$ since $\delta_n\to 0$.